# jquery to display images on divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am posting here again, I cannot seem to find a solution for this problem. I am using jquery and jstree plugin to build a tree and based on the node_id of the jstree, I am showing some images on divs. The problem I am facing is that some images are not loading eventhough they are there. When I experienced this problem, I verified that the image in question actually not loading by checking the width of the image. Below is the code. How can I make sure to load image before displaying it. Again, any help with this greatly appreciated as I am very new to jquery:

```
(document).ready(function () {
    $("#div1").jstree({
        "xml_data": {
            "ajax": {
                "url": "tree.xml"
            },
            "xsl": "nest"
        },
        "plugins": ["themes", "xml_data", "ui", "types"]
    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
        var node_id = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
        if (node_id.indexOf("TEAM") >= 0) var teamA;
        var teamB;
        teamA = "image/" + node_id + "-scores.png";
        teamB = "image/" + node_id + "-standing.png";
        img1 = new Image;
        img1.src = teamA;
        img2 = new Image;
        img2.src = teamB;
        $("#div2").html(img1);
        $("#div3").html(img2);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

[`$.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) takes an HTML string. Call [`$.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead which takes nodes or jQuery objects

```
    $("#div2").append(img1);
    $("#div3").append(img2);
```

Comment: Will the images now display when they are 100% loaded?

Comment: @AndreasNilsson Just like any other image that gets appended to the DOM. , I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: .append will not work for me. Everytime, I click on a node, the same will be appended to the image.

Comment: @Anreas Nilsson, the answer to your question is yes. Images are in a directory and when the browser loads them, they are displayed. How can I make sure to load them before displaying them?

Comment: @MikeDude  `append` does work for you, the rest of your code may not passing the right parameters. For example, where does `data` come from? It's the event's data, but you didn't set event data when creating the handler. Create a http://jsfiddle.net and others can help you a lot more easily

Comment: @Juan Mendes, append works but that is not what I am looking for. append keeps adding the same images to the same div every time a node is clicked.

Comment: @MikeDude I already gave you clues into what may be wrong. Where does `data` come from? Your comment that "it keeps adding the same images" is almost useless if you don't show some code that we can run. http://jsfiddle.net is your friend

Answer (score 0):

you can use the jQuery.html, but you have to supply a string (something like '[image]') instead of an Image object.
You can try convert your image objects to strings, Maybe youll find this link helpful: http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx

Comment: why would you want to do this, there is gotta be a easy solution for this.